# "Truck Transportation of Freight" would include tanker trucks that transport NGLs, correct? I'm looking at the Producer Price Index of transport

Tags: microeconomics, price, price-index

The producer price index I am referring to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXQU6.png)

There are other categories as well, but I'm concerned specifically with "Truck Transportation of Freight":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnf8q.png)

I assume tanker trucks would be part of this category since "freight" can any good or commodity in bulk.

Source of PPI index: https://data.bts.gov/stories/s/Transportation-and-Inflation/f9jm-cqwe#producer-price-index